# Can i include angular 1 component without custom tag or selector

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have angular 1 component:

```js
angular.module('main').directive('globalNotification', (_, moment, $modal, Auth, Payments, adds) => ({
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: '/client/directive/global-global-notification/global-notification.html',
```

And previously it was rendered in index as `<global-notification></global-notification>` But now i have angular 1 and vue js working together and Vue complaining about that custom component because it is not related to vue.

So, question can i somehow render component like this `<div global-notification></div>` to remove error from console. Is there are any pitfalls in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that in your case, you can just change restriction from `E` to `A`.

```js
restrict: 'A',
```

```html
<div global-notification></div>
```

As documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) says:

```
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches comment
```